# Insert Multiple XML tags as Salesforce records via mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to extract multiple tags from XML and insert them as Salesforce records. however, somehow I am only last record gets inserted and rest all I think are overwritten by the last one, the reason I think because I am using same variable name  "records" to store records but as soon as I change the variable name to something else mulesoft throws error an error, unidentified variable, how to handle this?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
---
[{  
    Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_ID__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
    Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Name__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
    Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Number__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no", 
    attributes: {
        "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c",
        "referenceId": "SO"
    },
    PBSI__Sales_Order_Lines__r: {
        records: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"product-lineitems".*ns0#"product-lineitem" map ( e , lineindex ) -> {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c",
                "referenceId": e.ns0#"product-id"
            },                      
                 PBSI__Price__c: e.ns0#"base-price" - (e.ns0#"tax"/e.ns0#"quantity"),
                 PBSI__Tax_Value__c: e.ns0#tax/e.ns0#quantity,
                 PBSI__ItemDescription__c: e.ns0#"product-name",
                 PBSI__Quantity_Needed__c: e.ns0#quantity,
                 "PBSI__Item__c": e.ns0#"custom-attributes".ns0#"custom-attribute"          
             
        }

    },
    PBSI__Sales_Order_Lines__r: {
        records: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"shipping-lineitems".*ns0#"shipping-lineitem" map ( s, slindex) -> {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c",
                "referenceId": s.ns0#"shipment-id"
            },
                PBSI__Price__c: s.ns0#"base-price" - s.ns0#"tax",
                PBSI__Tax_Value__c: s.ns0#tax,
                PBSI__ItemDescription__c: s.ns0#"lineitem-text",
                PBSI__Quantity_Needed__c: 1,
                "PBSI__Item__c": "a0a1x000001PmTc"                                      
        }
        
    },
    
    
    
        
    PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute"
        filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")) [0]      
}]
```

input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order order-no="00000907" xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
    <order-date>2020-07-10T08:57:05.076Z</order-date>
    <current-order-no>00000907</current-order-no>
    <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>54.17</net-price>
            <tax>10.83</tax>
            <gross-price>65.00</gross-price>
            <base-price>65.00</base-price>
            <lineitem-text>Travel pillow</lineitem-text>
            <tax-basis>65.00</tax-basis>
            <position>1</position>
            <product-id>116065</product-id>
            <product-name>Travel pillow</product-name>
            <quantity unit="">1.0</quantity>
            <tax-rate>0.2</tax-rate>
            <shipment-id>00004505</shipment-id>
            <gift>false</gift>
            <custom-attributes>
                <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscProductId">a0a1x000001Pjhj</custom-attribute>
            </custom-attributes>
        </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
    <shipping-lineitems>
        <shipping-lineitem>
            <net-price>4.99</net-price>
            <tax>1.00</tax>
            <gross-price>5.99</gross-price>
            <base-price>5.99</base-price>
            <lineitem-text>Shipping</lineitem-text>
            <tax-basis>5.99</tax-basis>
            <item-id>STANDARD_SHIPPING</item-id>
            <shipment-id>00004505</shipment-id>
            <tax-rate>0.2</tax-rate>
        </shipping-lineitem>
    </shipping-lineitems>
</order>
```

Comment: You mentioned an error and Salesforce connector usage, but you didn't provide any details. That seems to be fundamental for the error. Please add the complete error message from the log, the flow in XML with the DataWeave transformer and Salesforce connector operation, and the XML input to DataWeave. All in textual comment in the question please.

Comment: Hi aled, there is no error, shipping-lineitems record is inserted but not product-lineitems, I want both to be inserted, I updated the input XML in the original post now

Comment: It doesn't appear that the DataWeave transformation is not working. You should try to understand if the data is correctly formatted for the Salesforce connector. There are not details about the Salesforce operation in the question.

Comment: You are right, I formatted the JSON structure a bit and now it worked, updated working

Comment: Please add an answer showing how you resolved so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

restructured working code. more info in document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite_sobject_tree.htm#topic-title

```
%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
    ---
    [{  
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_ID__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Name__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Number__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no", 
        attributes: {
            "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c",
            "referenceId": "SO"
        },
        PBSI__Sales_Order_Lines__r: {   
            records: [
                        {
                            (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"product-lineitems".*ns0#"product-lineitem" map ( e , lineindex ) -> {
                            "attributes": {"type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c","referenceId": e.ns0#"product-id"},                     
                             PBSI__Price__c: e.ns0#"base-price" - (e.ns0#"tax"/e.ns0#"quantity"),
                             PBSI__Tax_Value__c: e.ns0#"tax"/e.ns0#quantity,
                             PBSI__ItemDescription__c: e.ns0#"product-name",
                             PBSI__Quantity_Needed__c: e.ns0#quantity,
                             "PBSI__Item__c": e.ns0#"custom-attributes".ns0#"custom-attribute"  
                            })
                        },
                        {
                            (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"shipping-lineitems".*ns0#"shipping-lineitem" map ( s, slindex) -> {
                            "attributes": {"type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c","referenceId": s.ns0#"shipment-id"},    
                            PBSI__Price__c: s.ns0#"base-price" - s.ns0#"tax",
                            PBSI__Tax_Value__c: s.ns0#tax,
                            PBSI__ItemDescription__c: s.ns0#"lineitem-text",
                            PBSI__Quantity_Needed__c: 1,
                            "PBSI__Item__c": "a0a1x000001PmTc"                                      
                            })
                        }
                    
                    ]            
        },  
        PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute"
            filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")) [0]      
    }]
```